# How to output async/observable data in Ionicframework?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, observable

I am following this tutorial on LinkedIn Learning https://www.linkedin.com/learning/ionic-4-0-essential-training/implementing-the-detail-page-design But I wasn't able to output the data fetched from URL.

I have already tried to add *ngIf="(activityDetail | async)" and it works. But it shows `Cannot read property 'id' of null`

Here's my `ActivityDetail` view

```
 <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>ActivityDetail</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-header>
          <ion-card-title>Test {{(activityDetail | async).id}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-header>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

Here's my `ActivityDetail.ts`

```
export class ActivityDetailPage implements OnInit {
  activityDetail: Observable<Activity>

  constructor(activityService: ActivityService, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    const activityID = activatedRoute.snapshot.params['activityID'];
    this.activityDetail = activityService.getActivity(activityID);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Cannot read property 'id' of null on my console. I should output the ID of my activity in my view.

Comment: {{(activityDetail | async)?.id}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{(activityDetail | async)?.id}}
```

Since you are using async pipe the observable was not complete so it is looking for attr id which is not there yet use the `?.` notation for possible null checks